# Moved a file with mv, now I can' t find it anymore!

Tags: mv

This is the command I used!

```
sudo mv '/home/alex/Desktop/elementaryos-0.4-stable-amd64.20160921.iso' Computer
```

I can't find it anymore, I wanted it to put it on Computer to make sure that UnetBootin can see it, but didn't succeed..

Comment: If `Computer` is a subdirectory of the directory you were in, you will find the file in that directory. Most likely however, there isn't such a directory, and you just renamed the file to `Computer`...

Comment: I think I found it and checked the size and it matched..how can I reverse the process?

Comment: if you just renamed the file, there's nothing really to do. If UnetBootin cares about file extensions, just rename with the extension: `mv Computer elementary.iso`

Comment: Ty, I got the file back!

Comment: No worries :) would you like to answer your own question?

Comment: Sure, gonna edit it!

Comment: don't put the answer in the question itself, but in the answer space down below :)

Answer (score 2):

That command renamed my file Computer, and moved it to a folder that I was able to find it with search option. After that I renamed back to ele....iso and moved it to the desktop!